# make an element rotate based on the direction of motion with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transform, mousemove

I have created a mockup of a "kite flying" page that a client requested, which makes the kite follow the cursor around the screen. I would like to have it rotate so that it looks like the kite is traveling in the direction of the movement.

I would like to do something like:

```
transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 25deg); //TURN KITE TO THE RIGHT
transform: rotate3d(0, -1, -1, 25deg); //TURN KITE TO THE LEFT
```

But I don't know enough about JS to set up the function so that if the movement on the X-axis is increasing, it rotates right, and if it is decreasing, it rotates left.

Demo in question: http://stoysnet.com/clients/wingsofthewind/flyme/

Pardon my messy code... I am very new at Javascript and CSS animations.

EXTRA: If anyone has suggestions on how to make the "string" so that it A) moves left and right as currently shown, but also B) tips so that it is pointing toward/connected to the kite, I am open to suggestions.

---

EDIT: Full code of page shown here (cleaned up a bit), so others can still view it when the mockup is removed:

```js
// SCRIPT FOR CURSOR FOLLOW
             $(document).on('mousemove', (event) => {
                 $('.follower').css({
                     left: event.clientX,
                     top: event.clientY/1.5 -100,
                 });
                 $('.string').css({
                     left: event.clientX,
                 });
             });
// END SCRIPT FOR CURSOR FOLLOW
        
// SCRIPT FOR SWAP IMAGE
            function pickKite(kite) {
                document.getElementById("flyme").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + kite + ")";
            }
// END SCRIPT FOR SWAP IMAGE
```

```css
    @keyframes animatedBackground {
     from { background-position: 0 0; }
     to { background-position: 100% 0; }
    }
    @keyframes windy {
        0% {
            transform: translateX(-30%) translateY(-30%);
        }
        25% {
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        }
        50% {
            transform: translateX(-80%) translateY(-30%);
        }
        75% {
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-10%);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translateX(-30%) translateY(-30%);
        }
    }
    body {
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    .container {
        width:100%;
        height:100vh;
        background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/ak3aIyl.png);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 0px 0px;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        animation: animatedBackground 180s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: animatedBackground 180s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation: animatedBackground 180s linear infinite;
        -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 180s linear infinite;
        cursor:crosshair;
    }
    .follower {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/i4xmPPt.png);
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: contain;
        transition-duration: 1800ms;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        position: fixed;
        left:50%;
        top:50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform-origin:50% 50%;
        animation: windy 20s ease-in-out infinite;
        -ms-animation: windy 20s ease-in-out infinite;
        -moz-animation: windy 20s ease-in-out infinite;
        -webkit-animation: windy 20s ease-in-out infinite;
    }
    .string {
        width: 2px;
        height: 400px;
        background:#FFFFFF;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        transition-duration: 1000ms;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        position: fixed;
        left:50%;
        top:100%;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform-origin:100% 50%;
    }
    .kite-selector {
        position: absolute;
        bottom:10px;
        right:10px;
        width:300px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.31);
    }
    .kite-selector div {
        float:left;
        margin-left:15px;
    }
    label > input{ /* HIDE RADIO */
        visibility: hidden; /* Makes input not-clickable */
        position: absolute; /* Remove input from document flow */
    }
    label > input + img{ /* IMAGE STYLES */
        cursor:pointer;
        background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.00);
    }
    label > input:checked + img{ /* (RADIO CHECKED) IMAGE STYLES */
        background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <div class="follower" id="flyme"></div>

        <div class="string">String Position Marker</div>
        
<!-- KITE IMAGE SELECTOR -->
        <div class="kite-selector">
            <h3 style="margin:10px;">Select your kite:</h3>
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="kite" value="https://i.imgur.com/i4xmPPt.png" checked onClick="pickKite(this.value);"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/i4xmPPt.png" style="max-height:50px;" alt="kite1"></label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="kite" value="https://i.imgur.com/iXRQF77.png" onClick="pickKite(this.value);"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/iXRQF77.png" style="max-height:50px;" alt="kite2"></label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="kite" value="https://i.imgur.com/L3IA1hX.png" onClick="pickKite(this.value);"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/L3IA1hX.png" style="max-height:50px;" alt="kite3"></label>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
<!-- END KITE IMAGE SELECTOR -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please also post your code here in a stack snippet so that this question can still be useful to someone else even after your site ceases to exist.

Comment: @ecg8 Good call. Updated and cleaned up the snippet code a bit.